# for-loops being used as while-loops (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, while-loop

I noticed that in Python it is possible to mimic while-loops using for-loops (I know very little about coding). I was then trying to construct two identical while-loops using the two different formulations. It seems to me that it is the case here (is it?)

```
# for-loop formulation
index = [0]
for a in index:
    if a < 6:
       index.append(a + 1) 

# while-loop formulation
index = [0]
while index[-1] < 6:
    index.append(index[-1] + 1)
```

What confuses me is that I thought that once the list index is updated/changed the for-loop would restart from the beginning, as the list could have changed dramatically at any cycle. For example if you run

```
#3
index = [0]
for a in index:
    print a
    if a < 6:
       index.append(a+1)
       if a > 3:
           index = [1, 3]
    print index
```

you get the output

```
0
[0, 1]
1
[0, 1, 2]
2
[0, 1, 2, 3]
3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
4
[1, 3]
5
[1, 3]
```

where the a is not part of the new index [1, 3] in the last step.
Hence three questions:

1. Are the two programs #1 and #2 at the beginning  different  (for example, is their computational effort different?)
2. What is happening in program #3 (why is the 'for a in index:' command apparently ignored in the last step?), and how does the for-loop react to changes in the updating index in general?
3. Are there general guidelines on using for loops as while loops (I noticed that I found it helpful in a specific case, so I was wondering for some general tips in this direction).

Comment: Are you more interested in a python answer or a "general" answer?

Comment: The behaviour isn’t well-documented in Python (there’s [a vague note about it](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) and that’s all; discussion at https://bugs.python.org/issue32767) and relying on it will confuse people reading your code. Go with the more explicit `while` loop.

Comment: Ideally, you should not modify the size of the collection being iterated over. The while loop just checks the last value of the list, not iterates over the content

Comment: agree with @cricket_007: for-loop and while-loop are different. If you will disassemble code you will see that for-loop setups iterator, while while-loop do not. Create functions for each loop and disassemble them with [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module.

Comment: "What confuses me is that I thought that once the list index is updated/changed the for-loop would restart from the beginning" it does not.

Comment: @syntonym: kind of both, maybe a bit more interested in a python answer.

Comment: @sKwa: can you refer to the code I wrote if possible? (That would make it more clear to me)

Comment: [Worth reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/364696), since what you're doing will inevitably lead to other invalid uses of iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two are basically the same, in that they will run the same number of iterations under various circumstances, and will leave `index` in the same state. If you replace `index.append(a+1)` with `index.append(a)`, the `for` loop will run forever; similarly, if you replace `index.append(index[-1] + 1)` with `index.append(index[-1])`, the `while` loop will run forever. It's a bit fraught to modify a list you're iterating over like this, but it's sometimes a reasonable tactic.

What's happening with the `for` loop, by the way, is that when you start it, an iterator is created that gives `index[0]`, then `index[1]`, then `index[2]`, etc., until it gets to an `index[N]` that doesn't exist. This iterator doesn't know or care that you're changing the list, so if you make the list longer, it will happily go on longer.

In program #3, there's some confusion of scoping. The iterator that's created when you enter the for loop doesn't care that you're reassigning the variable `index` inside the for loop: it just keeps iterating over the original list. When you do `index.append(a+1)` the first few times, that does affect the original list; but as soon as you do `index = [1, 3]`, `index` no longer refers to the original list, so nothing you do to it affects the remaining course of the iteration. The last value that gets added is `5`, because once `a` gets to `4` and `a+1` is appended to index, `index` is clobbered and nothing more gets appended to the original list.

Lastly, the clobbering of `index` persists outside the for loop: it will have the value `[1, 3]` when the loop is done.